# tkinter display large csv

Tags: python, csv, tkinter

I am struggling around with a little problem.
I want to display data from a csv-file.
Reading is no problem, but displaying the data with Tkinter is.

I want to display the data with a short for-loop :

```
lang = 100 # 100 Entries
for i in range(lang):
    for j in range(39):
        button = Button(frame, padx=7, pady=7, text=datei[i][j])
        button.grid(row=i+1, column=j, sticky='news')
```

My problem is, that displaying that 100 lines is done in nice time.
Displaying nearly all rows (>250000) needs too much time.

I haven't found code to just "display page by page" or to slide the data.
Another idea is sorting by clicking at first row.

Are there any tricks to display that data ?

Maybe Button is wrong, I will try label next.

Thank you for your ideas :)

Comment: Please don't use buttons. Especially since you don't plan on any action to occur if these buttons are pressed.

Comment: Maybe Tktable mentioned in [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7209562/5781248) would work.