# Open Excel file inside GUI with Python

Tags: python, excel, csv, user-interface, tkinter

I want to create a GUI that consists of two sections.
one of the section is to show images
the other section is to open an excel file inside the GUI to fill it with data.
(open the excel program itself) or any alterative way.

I can not find any way to do it. Is it possible to do to with tkinter ?
if no what other tool can I use?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Which widget do you use for a Excel like table in tkinter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7208961/which-widget-do-you-use-for-a-excel-like-table-in-tkinter)

Comment: I think this will help: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Bn1n1diGv_0

Comment: no. I want to physically open an excel file inside the GUI to be easier to fill in data.

Comment: @Shatha What do you mean by that? Do you want to open the actual excel program from the GUI or do you want the table to be shown inside the GUI?

Comment: @TheLizzard I want to open an actual excel program inside the GUI. so the images and excel file be next to each other. and I can fill the excel file with information in the images.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `os` module has a simple method for that called `startfile()`. You pass in 2 arguments:

- the path for a file
- the program to open it with (optional, automatic if omitted)

Below is an example:

```
import os
os.startfile("dir1\\dir2\\dir3\\file.ext")
```

I think this should satisfy your needs.